# Reading data into list nodes

Tags: c, syntax

I am supposed to create a linked list with each node having structure:

```
struct stack{
    char paint;
    int index;
    struct stack *next;
}
typedef struct stack s;
```

I am Supposed to create linked list with m nodes by reading m inputs such as:

```
A 7

B 2

C 1

D 4 ....
```

so I tried using a for loop
like this which is failing and also i tried to sequential `scanf`s like

```
scanf("%c",&c);

scanf("%d",&b);
```

I also tried this:

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    scanf("%c %d",&c,&b);
    temp=(s *)malloc(sizeof(s));
    temp->paint=c;
    temp->index=b;
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
    temp=NULL;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am actually scared of `scanf` so I usually use `getchar` all the time and if possible please explain how `scanf` works when inputting from terminal or files which have `n` rows of inputs. And also alternative statement of `while((c=getchar())!='\n')` using `scanf`?

Comment: Can you clarify *...which is failing...*? Failing in what way?

Comment: You should really check the results of your function calls; in particular make sure `scanf` returns 2 (read 2 fields).  And you're not reading the whitespace after each line (add a space to the end of your format string).

Comment: @lurker it is going into the for loop and nothing is happening, all i can see is the terminal waiting for input

Comment: @Dmitri There is not whitespace between inputs i just seperated them here so that it looks clean .sorry for the confusion

Comment: @sarat The whitespace I was referring to was the newlines that separate each line from the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `scanf` from

```
scanf("%c %d",&c,&b);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c %d",&c,&b);
//     ^Add a space before %c
```

The problem here is `scanf` is reading `\n` after you input a character value and an integer value and then pressing enter key.

A space before `%` will skip white space (also `\n`) and it will read the next character that is not white space.

Comment: Thank you so much @1336087 skipping the white space fixed the problem, i was frantically searching for whats wrong with the code

Comment: @sarat: You are welcome :) If your problem is resolved kindly click on the tick mark and accept an answer which was useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

In scanf, `%c` and `%1s` are not the same :

- `%c` reads next character, whatever it can be a space, a newline, ...
- `%1s` reads next printable character

In your use case, I think you should use

```
scanf("%1s %d",&c,&b);
```

to correctly skip eventual spaces an newline